# Is there a command line TFS tool to track a changeset between branches?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

Visual Studio 2010 has this nice GUI for allowing you to see the migration of a changeset between multiple branches.  I would like to get this information in text format via the command line if possible.  We run daily PowerShell scripts to check for unmerged changes between our Release branches and Trunk.  This makes sure we don't forget to propagate a bug fix back to Trunk.  However, what we are missing is the ability to then check if that same bug fix was propagated to a newer release branch e.g.:

```
Trunk ----------------------------------------------
      \                \
       \                ------- Release 2.0
        -- Release 1.0
```

We can easily check for unmerged changes between Release 1.0 and Trunk but we also want to make sure those changesets get propaged down into Release 2.0 as well.

Running `tf merge /candidate` between Trunk and Release 2.0 wouldn't be effective because we would get a bunch of changesets related to new features implemented after the 2.0 release.  Perhaps I could do a baseless merge candidate check (from Release 1.0 to Release 2.0)?  Or perhaps TFS 2012 provides some new command line option for changeset tracking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll probably want to use a combination of [`tf branches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcbx5yce.aspx) and [`tf merges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/656cs2x5). If these don't give you the information you need then I think you're going to be writing your own console application or powershell snapin using the TFS API